# Find number of records created and updated for each combination of keys in fact table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have  a fact table that looks like below table TBL. I have a requirement to find the number of records created and updated for each combination of keys. My required output looks like below output table.
Please find MS sql server script I did so far, However this query is performing very slow in production db because of huge data volume. Is there any way to rewrite same script in better way.

```
SELECT A.*,B.DateupdatedCount 
FROM
(
    SELECT DateKey
        ,Key1
        ,Key2
        ,Key3
        ,COUNT(*) AS DateCreatedCount
    FROM TBL Fact
    GROUP BY DateKey
        ,Key1
        ,Key2
        ,Key3
) A 
FULL JOIN 
(
    SELECT YEAR(DateUpdated) * 10000 + MONTH(DateUpdated) * 1000 + DAY(DateUpdated) AS DateKey
        ,Key1
        ,Key2
        ,Key3
        ,COUNT(*) AS DateUpdatedCount
    FROM TBL Fact
    GROUP BY DateUpdated
        ,Key1
        ,Key2
        ,Key3
) B ON A.DateKey = B.DateKey 
    AND A.Key1 = B.Key1 
    AND A.Key2 = B.Key2 
    AND A.Key3 = B.Key3
```

Source Table TBL:

```
DateKey |Key1|Key2|Key3|DateCreated|DateUpdated
20180101    1   1   3   1/1/2018    1/5/2018
20180102    1   1   3   1/2/2018    1/5/2018
20180103    1   1   3   1/3/2018    1/5/2018
20180104    1   1   3   1/4/2018    1/5/2018
20180105    1   1   3   1/5/2018    1/5/2018
20180106    6   2   4   1/6/2018    1/6/2018
20180107    6   2   4   1/7/2018    1/6/2018
20180108    6   2   4   1/8/2018    1/6/2018
20180109    6   2   4   1/9/2018    1/6/2018
20180110    6   2   4   1/10/2018   1/6/2018
```

Output Table:

```
DateKey  |Key1|Key2|Key3|DateCreatedCount   |DateUpdatedCount
20180101    1   1   3       1                    0
20180102    1   1   3       1                    0
20180103    1   1   3       1                    0
20180104    1   1   3       1                    0
20180105    1   1   3       1                    5
20180106    6   2   4       1                    5
20180107    6   2   4       1                    0
20180108    6   2   4       1                    0
20180109    6   2   4       1                    0
20180110    6   2   4       1                    0
```

Thanks in advance for your help..

Comment: If this table has a "huge data volume", it would be a good candidate for SSAS.

Comment: It would really help to see your data structures (meaning create table statements as well as indexes), approximate row counts in the tables and the actual execution plan. Anything less than those details is leaving people guessing.

Comment: What is the timing (# of min/secs) on each of the separate Selects?? A alone, then B alone?  and the total time on the full sql?